# Generate a URL for an Image?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs

Is there a way to create a URL for an image in ReactJS when having an input file?

I want to get that URL and store it in my database (MongoDB).

[image: Mockup image link of my idea in my form]

Comment: can you describe what you mean by get the image url? are you asking where that image exists in the local file system? are you talking about storing the image somewhere and generating a URL for that image?

Comment: Im talking about storing an image somewhere(such as MongoDB) when processing the file i chose from the Choose a file button. Image URL as in like https://images.pexels.com/photos/356378/pexels-photo-356378.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350

Comment: If there is any way to create a image URL such as this when choosing a file from the local folder or file system.

Comment: Well how does your server serve the assets? Just store the images in a folder your server is serving and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but in the client side there isnt a way. All file’s links are like `c://file/ID` where ID is a custom ID generate for each selection.

The best way is to send file in your backend. There you can store the file in some public directory and create the link for the file in this directory. Just like you do with static file. Then save in your database.